# How to set only few values of an enum as valuetype of a datagridviewcell?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, c#-4.0, datagridview

I need to set valuetype of a datagridviewcell to an enum's values for validation. How can I set it to only some values of that enum?

I can do

```
  dgv[i, j].ValueType = typeof(MyEnum);


  MyEnum { me, bro, sis, mom, dad }
```

But this validates for all enum values in `MyEnum`, ie it lets the user to type all values in `MyEnum` but nothing else. I need the user be able to type only `mom` and `dad`. How to achieve this?

Comment: One can decorate the individual enum with attributes which can be used to group the enums for later segregation in your situation. See my blog article which explains how one can put more information on an enum then reflect the information from that: [C# Using Extended Attribute Information on Objects](http://omegacoder.com/?p=28) EDIT Also as an aside one can use the Tag object to hold items as one loads up grids / combobox. see [C# Winforms and the Hidden Association Tag](http://omegacoder.com/?p=66)

Comment: See my edit about the Tag member which might be of service.

Comment: Thanks.. I'm seeing to it. let me test..

Comment: My question is by setting tag to those enum values, how am i possible to set only those values as the ValueType?

Comment: The Tag could hold the actual enum value or maybe even the group value you want.... Or the selected value (as an enum) could have an attribute and then its group divined from the attribute value off of the enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define another Enum as a subset of MyEnum:

```
enum MyEnum { me, bro, sis, mom, dad } 

enum Subset 
{ 
    mom = MyEnum.mom,
    dad = MyEnum.dad
}

dgv[i, j].ValueType = typeof(Subset);     

// to get the MyEnum value, cast it back:
MyEnum cellVal = (MyEnum)dgv[i, j].Value;
```